# Change in the pro tem mod team

Tags: discussion, moderation

Some folks may have noticed that justkt is no longer a moderator on Writers; she's bowed out as a mod because of lack of time. To replace her, Monica has been asked by the Stack Exchange team to take over, and she's agreed to do so.

[image: MonicaCellio]

Monica has been an active member here, particularly active in questions about tech writing and language. On top of being a [10k user on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio), she's also a moderator there.

Comment: Yaaaay! :D I for one am glad to see Monica join this awesome team.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, Neil and @Aarthi!

Comment: Welcome to the team Monica!

Comment: Someone just pointed out [this post](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/140/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) to me.  Should we reconcile these or just leave it alone?  (To be clear, *I* don't particularly care one way or the other, but I don't know about usual practice.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - That's from 2010, I'd not be overly concerned. I left a comment there anyway, linking here.

Comment: Works for me.  Someone asked me if the old one should be updated and I didn't know, so I figured I'd ask.